# Saving a gamlss model to an RDS format

Tags: save, glm, gamlss

I'm fitting an R `gamlss` model:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("g1",100),rep("g2",100),rep("g3",100)),
                 value = c(rgamma(100,rate=5,shape=3),rgamma(100,rate=5,shape=4),rgamma(100,rate=5,shape=5)))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels=c("g1","g2","g3"))
gamlss.fit <- gamlss::gamlss(formula = value ~ group, sigma.formula = ~group, data = df, family=gamlss.dist::GA(mu.link="log"))
```

This is what I get:

```
> gamlss.fit

Family:  c("GA", "Gamma") 
Fitting method: RS() 

Call:  gamlss::gamlss(formula = value ~ group, sigma.formula = ~group,      family = gamlss.dist::GA(mu.link = "log"), data = df) 

Mu Coefficients:
(Intercept)      groupg2      groupg3  
    -0.5392       0.2553       0.5162  
Sigma Coefficients:
(Intercept)      groupg2      groupg3  
   -0.66318      0.02355     -0.08610  

 Degrees of Freedom for the fit: 6 Residual Deg. of Freedom   294 
Global Deviance:     217.18 
            AIC:     229.18 
            SBC:     251.402
```

I want to save this `gamlss.fit` model in `RDS` format for later use. The `saveRDS` function works fine.

```
saveRDS(gamlss.fit, "my.gamlss.fit.RDS")
```

But then if I terminate the current `R` session, open a new one and read the `RDS` saved `gamlss.fit` model, I get:

```
Call:  gamlss::gamlss(formula = value ~ group, sigma.formula = ~group,
    family = gamlss.dist::GA(mu.link = "log"), data = df)

No coefficients


Degrees of Freedom: Total (i.e. Null);  294 Residual
Error in signif(x$null.deviance, digits) :
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

So I cannot really use this object for anything downstream.

I thought that `tidypredict`'s `parse_model` function might come in handy, but it doesn't seem to support parsing the `gamlss` model:

```
> gamlss.parsed.fit <- tidypredict::parse_model(gamlss.fit)
Error: Functions inside the formula are not supported.
- Functions detected: `gamlss`,`gamlss.dist`,`GA`. Use `dplyr` transformations to prepare the data.
```

This `saveRDS` is specific to `gamlss` because if I fit a `glm` model:

```
glm.fit <- glm(formula = value ~ group, data = df, family="Gamma"(link='log'))
```

Which gives:

```
> glm.fit

Call:  glm(formula = value ~ group, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      groupg2      groupg3  
    -0.5392       0.2553       0.5162  

Degrees of Freedom: 299 Total (i.e. Null);  297 Residual
Null Deviance:      93.25 
Residual Deviance: 79.99    AIC: 226.9
```

I'll get the same after reading it from the `RDS` saved file:

```
Call:  glm(formula = value ~ group, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      groupg2      groupg3
    -0.5392       0.2553       0.5162

Degrees of Freedom: 299 Total (i.e. Null);  297 Residual
Null Deviance:      93.25
Residual Deviance: 79.99    AIC: 226.9
```

BTW, `tidypredict`'s `parse_model` neither supports parsing a `glm` model:

```
> glm.parsed.fit <- tidypredict::parse_model(glm.fit)
Error: Functions inside the formula are not supported.
- Functions detected: `Gamma`. Use `dplyr` transformations to prepare the data.
```

Any idea if and how a `gamlss` model can be saved not using the `save` function, which its drawbacks are discussed [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/)